# Why do '' show up as &#39; (HTML Entity?) in my charts.js.erb file?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, morris.js

I am trying to create a simple bar chart in Morris.js, which will display the workload of an person, paired with their name. (name, workload) |key, value|

To do this, I have created a hash of the users name and their workload, @workloads. Then, in my charts.js.erb file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  Morris.Bar({
      element: 'workload-bar-chart',
      data: [
      <% @workloads.each do |key, value| %>
        <%= "{ y: '#{key}', a: #{value} }," %>
      <% end %>
      ],
      xkey: 'y',
      ykeys: ['a'],
      labels: ['Name'],
      hideHover: 'auto',
      resize: true
  });
});
```

This is the output that is rendered in the browser. (Safari, in case you ask.)

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      Morris.Bar({
          element: 'workload-bar-chart',
          data: [
            { y: &#39;Ronny&#39;, a: 0 },
            { y: &#39;Jeff&#39;, a: 24 },
            { y: &#39;Brad&#39;, a: 41 },
            { y: &#39;Janice&#39;, a: 2 },
            { y: &#39;Jose&#39;, a: 4 },
          ],
          xkey: 'y',
          ykeys: ['a'],
          labels: ['Name'],
          hideHover: 'auto',
          resize: true
      });
    });
```

Now, this doesn't work at all for Morris.js. The output I am trying to get is this:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      Morris.Bar({
          element: 'workload-bar-chart',
          data: [
            { y: 'Ronny', a: 0 },
            { y: 'Jeff', a: 24 },
            { y: 'Brad', a: 41 },
            { y: 'Janice', a: 2 },
            { y: 'Jose', a: 4 },
          ],
          xkey: 'y',
          ykeys: ['a'],
          labels: ['Name'],
          hideHover: 'auto',
          resize: true
      });
    });
```

When I code this in manually, it works perfectly, and I don't think anything is wrong with the hash itself. (It prints just fine in the view.) I simply need to stop my `'` from converting to `&#39;`, which I believe means that I need to escape it somehow. I think it is converting my `'` to an HTML Entity (decimal).

Just for reference, I know almost nothing about javascript, and I've only been coding with Ruby on Rails for just over a year.

Comment: On a side note, dumping data via ERB into javascript is an anti-pattern. Is usually better to load it with ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy answer is use `escape_javascript`. But what you most likely should be doing is using AJAX and consuming your own API.

Why?

1. Because you can test the javascript in Jasmine/ Mocha etc. without setting up an entire rails stack. You can also simply stub the ajax call in your tests.
2. By avoiding "dynamic" javascript you can compile all assets at deploy time.

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // I just assumed this path
    var promise = $.getJSON('/workloads.json');

    // Transform data
    promise.then(function(data){
        return $.map(data, function(item){
            return {
                y: item.name,
                a: item.foo
            }
        });
    });
    // Render chart
    promise.done(function(data){
        Morris.Bar({
          element: 'workload-bar-chart',
          data: data,
          xkey: 'y',
          ykeys: ['a'],
          labels: ['Name'],
          hideHover: 'auto',
          resize: true
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: While it is true that escape_javascript will work, this is clearly the correct way.

Comment: I noticed now that you can set the `xkey` and `ykey` in Morris so you could skip the whole transform data step.

Comment: Yes, I just tried setting the xkey and ykey in morris and it works perfectly. Thanks for returning to point that out.

Answer (score 1):

try [`escape_javascript`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) in your view

```
  <% @workloads.each do |key, value| %>
    <%=j "{ y: '#{key}', a: #{value} }," %> # j is an alias for escape_javascript
  <% end %>
```